# MapReduce to process GZip compressed RCFile

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, gzip

I want to access files in HDFS which are GZip compressed RCFiles (stored using HIVE) using a MapReduce program.

I want to process these files and write them back in the same format - (RCFile + GZip) using the same MapReduce program.

Can you please share your experience / thoughts / MapReduce java snippets / links or any pointers pertaining to these ?

Thanks in Advance!